# Python: how to change a Multipolygon in string format to list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, geospatial

I'm trying to create a GeoSpatial Query in MongoDB with a MultiPolygon. I have previously performed in Python. The problem is that the MultiPolygon has string format and, in order to use it in MongoDB. I would need it as an array.

The multipolygon is:

```
[[[-73.94193078816193, 40.70072523469547], [-73.9443878859649, 40.70042452378256], [-73.94424286147482, 40.69969927964773]]], 

[[[-73.94409591260093, 40.69897295461309], [-73.94394947271304, 40.69822127983908],[-73.84913837242902, 40.698282741201865]]]
```

How can I do it?

I hope you can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `numpy.array()` ?

```
import numpy as np

x= [[[-73.94193078816193, 40.70072523469547], [-73.9443878859649, 40.70042452378256], [-73.94424286147482, 40.69969927964773]]], 
[[[-73.94409591260093, 40.69897295461309], [-73.94394947271304, 40.69822127983908],[-73.84913837242902, 40.698282741201865]]]

new_x = np.array(x)
```